# RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, gpu

I want to train a gpt2 model in my laptop and I have a GPU in it and my os is windows , but I always got this error in python:

```
torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available
```

when I tried to check the availability of GPU in the python console, I got true:

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
Out[4]: True
```

but I can't get the version by

```
nvcc version 
#or  nvcc --version
NameError: name 'nvcc' is not defined
```

I use this command to install CUDA

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

What can I do to make the GPU available for python?

Comment: What version of pytorch CUDA did you install ? And what's the output of ```nvcc version``` ?

Comment: I use this command to install CUDA { conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch}

Comment: NameError: name 'nvcc' is not defined

Comment: Are you using Mac/linux or windows ?

Comment: windows  10 ........

Comment: Can you please edit the question so that everything I asked is in the question ? Your questions all this information.

Comment: `nvcc --version` isn't a command you execute within a python interpreter, you run it from the command line of a terminal. But it is an irrelevant test because the conda supplied 'cuda-toolkit' is only runtime libraries and it doesn't include development tools like nvcc, which you don't need for your use case. Executing that command tells you exactly *nothing* about whether your conda based setup works or not. The more fundamental questions are (a) do you have an NVIDIA GPU? and (b) have you installed a recent driver for it.

Comment: Yes, I have an NVIDIA GPU and I installed a recent driver yesterday.

Comment: nvcc --version output :::                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                      
  nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Mar_21_19:24:09_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.3, V11.3.58
Build cuda_11.3.r11.3/compiler.29745058_0

Comment: See now you have broken things. You don't need and should not have installed the CUDA 11.3 toolkit. All you need to make this work is a recent driver and what conda installs for you. Do more and you will break things

Comment: And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that the CUDA drivers that I was trying to install, didn't support my GPU model. In your case, please check which CUDA driver supports your GPU model. You are now installing 10.2. In my case CUDA 11.0 and 11.2 supported my GPU model but not 11.3 which I was trying to install.

If you got the same error after a while, which can happen if you run a cloud vm which hardware can be updated automatically, here is how to solve it:

Remove CUDA drivers

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

Then reinstall the drivers as follows. Note! in this case I have debian distro on x64 system.

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/debian11/x86_64/cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo add-apt-repository contrib
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

Get the correct commands that works for your distro and system from the link: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux

Good luck!

Comment: I used your idea got this error: E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Answer (score -1):

1:Make sure to install the nvidia drivers using the following resource
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
When installing the drivers be sure to check the operating system
2:If it is training your models and you are using your terminal you can check the following repository
https://github.com/paulmunyao/visual-chatgpt -under the quick start section

Comment: Please format your answer a little bit and edit it to make sure you meet our [guidelines for self-promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/188174).

Answer (score -4):

Make sure that you have CUDA installed. For me, I installed it from the NVIDIA directory: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Comment: No, this is not going to solve the problem. The anaconda command installs all the necessary runtime components. A separate CUDA toolkit is not required and would like break or complicate things further

Comment: I installed cuda in Windows and then remove the tools but in both cases gpu doesn't work in python

Comment: I need ordered steps to activate the GPU and work with it on my laptop please.,